How to correct the python library installation error?
When I try to run pip install pandas on my terminal I get the following error:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python312\python.exe"  "C:\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe" install pandas': The system cannot find the file specified.


can you try python -m pip install -U --force pip. It uninstalls pip from your machine if installed and then installs a fresh version. Once installation completed, press enter. Then try to install pandas with pip install pandas.
Let us know if this works

have you checked the path in   [ Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > System variables > 'Path' ] ? Modify path Variable.
after modifying the 'PATH' here, restart your command prompt and try running python --version and pip --version again to ensure they are recognized.
